# Tooltip on a cell reactable R

Tags: r

The `reactable` [documentation](https://glin.github.io/reactable/articles/cookbook/cookbook.html#tooltips-1) provides one exemple on adding a tooltip on headers.

Here is an exemple to add a tooltip for a cell.

```
data <- mtcars[1:5, c("mpg", "cyl")]
data$tooltipcell<-"<span title='your content'>this is a car</span>"
with_tooltip <- function(value, tooltip) {
  span(style = "text-decoration: underline; text-decoration-style: dotted;", title = tooltip, value)
}

reactable(
  data,
  columns = list(
    mpg = colDef(name="mpg"),
    cyl = colDef(header = with_tooltip("cyl", "Number of cylinders")),
    tooltipcell=colDef(html = TRUE)
  )
)
```

Comment: I don't get the question

Comment: That was not a question indeed. Just to provide an exemple with tooltip in cell through reactable. I was looking for this in the documentation but only a similar exemple exists with header.

Comment: Thanks. This does not work for nested tables (nor does the example in the referenced documentation)

Comment: For those stumbling on the topic : the author of reactable explains how to add beautiful tooltips for each cell, using the tippy package here : https://github.com/glin/reactable/issues/220